# get line number with bash in R

Tags: r, bash, system

using

```
system(paste("wc -l file_1.txt"))
```

in R to obtain the line number of a file
The output is

1601 file_1.txt

My problem is that if I type 
    system(paste("wc -l file_1.txt"))->kt
and then

```
kt
[1] 0
```

I would need to be able to say whether

```
system(paste("wc -l file_1.txt"))->kt
kt[1]==1600
```

or not..but I cant access the elements from the system commadn or the printout...how can i do that to somehow check whether the file has 1600 lines without reading it into R first...

Answer (score 5):

`system` only returns the return value of your command by default, you need to use its [`intern`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) argument:

```
system(paste("wc -l banner.p"), intern=T)->kt
```

`kt` would then be some string like

```
<lines> <filename>
```

And then you could parse the string.